# Library for Discontinuous Galerkin method: FEniCS vs deal.ii

Tags: libraries, fenics, discontinuous-galerkin, deal.ii, software-recommendation

I am aware that both FEniCS and deal.ii are capable of solving problems with Discontinuous Galerkin (DG) method. I would like to specifically know if any of these two softwares can cater these requirements. Other software suggestions are also welcome; I am aware of these two because they are actively developed. I am specifically interested in solving hyperbolic (wave-dominated) problems.

1. Local DG implementation
2. User defined numerical flux function.
3. Access and modify nodal/modal basis function coefficients. This is required because I want to implement limiters (for shock capturing).
4. Support for both structured and unstructured meshes.

I request FEniCS/deal.ii users to kindly answer.

Comment: There is the DUNE / DUNE PDELAB ecosystem, where some DG methods are already implemented, but I can't really recommend them for lack of Documentation. If I where you, I would go with whatever package has the most active users and the best documentation. That might influence your overall productivity more than minor differences in the implementations. (my 2 cents)

Comment: I would also take into account the type of element you want to use. Dealii supports only quads/hexes while fenics focuses on simplex elements ( triangles and tetrahedron). I have found dealii to be quite easy to use once you get past the initial confusion that always occurs with large codes.

Comment: Hi, we are developing MoFEM; the DG tutorial support mixed meshes with triangles and quads, arbitrary approximation orders. The tutorial example is for 2d but can extend to 3d.

http://mofem.eng.gla.ac.uk/mofem/html/tutorial_dg_poisson.html

Also, you can calculate trace skeletons from other spaces, i.e. H1, H-div, and H-curl. For example, to solve the Krochoff plate problem,

http://mofem.eng.gla.ac.uk/mofem/html/tutorial_plate.html

Or you can do advection problems,
https://youtu.be/Hz2L4caSAv8

Answer (score 2):

For Hyperbolic PDEs I can highly recommend [Trixi](https://github.com/trixi-framework/Trixi.jl), a (if you want) high order Discontinuous Galerkin based solver with adaptive mesh refining capabilities written in `Julia`.
Both [structured](https://github.com/trixi-framework/Trixi.jl/blob/f924c969c0dba546c01a179603984b9d0d1ae0b2/src/meshes/structured_mesh.jl) and [unstructured](https://github.com/trixi-framework/Trixi.jl/blob/f924c969c0dba546c01a179603984b9d0d1ae0b2/src/meshes/unstructured_mesh.jl) meshes are supported.
Furthermore, the addition of custom [initial](https://github.com/trixi-framework/Trixi.jl/blob/f924c969c0dba546c01a179603984b9d0d1ae0b2/examples/structured_1d_dgsem/elixir_euler_sedov.jl#L16)/[boundary](https://github.com/trixi-framework/Trixi.jl/blob/f924c969c0dba546c01a179603984b9d0d1ae0b2/examples/tree_2d_dgsem/elixir_lbm_couette.jl#L51) conditions, [fluxes](https://github.com/trixi-framework/Trixi.jl/blob/f924c969c0dba546c01a179603984b9d0d1ae0b2/src/equations/compressible_euler_1d.jl#L260) or entire [equations](https://trixi-framework.github.io/Trixi.jl/stable/tutorials/adding_new_scalar_equations/) is relatively easy.

Implementing limiters is up to you, but you have access to the basis function coefficients at all times.

Comment: thanks very much for answering. I had asked this question long back and went ahead with deal.ii. And I don't regret my decision (yet ?) :)

Comment: Glad to hear, I just stumbled over the question and wanted to take the possibility to promote `Trixi` mostly for those, who might come across this question.

Comment: @Zxcvasdf, do you have any specific reasons to use deal.ii in response to your own question? Could be a nice answer to say why you chose it and don't regret choosing it.

Comment: @user9794, I took this decision because of the following: (i) very very well documented code, (ii) availability of plenty of examples/tutorials with detailed explanations, (iii) very active and responsive developer/use group. I cannot compare the technical capabilities because I haven't used other softwares. But the quality and quantity of help available to understand and use the software made me chose this :)